# Possible to send text/strings as input?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I was successfully able to create my own custom commands for Google Assistant using the `hotword.py` example.

I want to be able to send data to the Assistant as text so I can have custom feedback. Something like `repeat after me your lights are on` so the Assistant would respond with `your lights are on`.

I tried settings the `event.args`: `event.args["text"] = 'repeat after me your lights are on'`

And it the output was

```
    ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {'text': 'repeat after me your lights are on'}
```

like it was supposed to be, but it doesn't actually execute the "spoken" command. I'm supposing it's because I'm setting the `event.args["text"]` variable AFTER the data is already sent, but BEFORE it's printed to the console.

If there is an alternate method of getting the Assistant to speak a string/text, that would work as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look example in [textinput example](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py#L99)